# TypeError: window() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'timeColumn' and 'windowDuration' Explicitly there though

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the titled error coming through for the window() method. Yet I even tried putting these in explicitly as seen below. (I was getting the error before I tried this and our code demo showed it working with out the explicit call.)

This is in Spark - Python on Databricks. Does anyone have any ideas?

The schema for the Date column is created with this:

```
StructField('Date', TimestampType(), True), \
```

This following code makes the dataframe going into the problematic line:

```
countFifaStaticHash = staticFIFAdf.withColumn('Hashtags', f.explode(f.split('Hashtags',',')))
```

Here is a short sample of what the above looks like when .show() is run:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Xbe.png)

```
staticCountedHash = countFifaStaticHash.groupBy(f.window(timeColumn="Date", windowDuration="60 minutes", slideDuration="30 minutes"), 'Hashtags').agg(f.count('Hashtags').alias('Hash_ct')).filter(f.col('Hash_ct')>100).orderBy(f.window().asc(),f.col('Hash_ct').desc())
staticCountedHash.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to order by the value of the window column. In that case, you can alias the group by window and order by the aliased window:

```
staticCountedHash = countFifaStaticHash.groupBy(
    f.window(timeColumn="Date", windowDuration="60 minutes", slideDuration="30 minutes").alias('window'), 
    'Hashtags'
).agg(
    f.count('Hashtags').alias('Hash_ct')
).filter(
    f.col('Hash_ct') > 100
).orderBy(
    f.col('window').asc(),
    f.col('Hash_ct').desc()
)
```

Comment: OMG! I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!!